# Redux Saga Multiple Put don't work without Delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to dispatch 2 put actions from my saga, however, only the first put seems to work. I inspected the action flow, using Redux DevTools, and it shows that both actions are called.

```
function* root() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery('SET_DATA'), updateSections)
    ]);
}

function* updateSections(action) {

   ...some logic

   if (someValue === 1) {
       yield put({ type: 'UNHIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section1' });
       yield put({ type: 'HIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section2' });

   } else {
       yield put({ type: 'UNHIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section2' });
       yield put({ type: 'HIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section1' });
   }
}
```

I managed to get both actions to successfully dispatched by adding a delay between the 2 yields, like so:

```
if (someValue === 1) {
    yield put({ type: 'UNHIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section1' });
    delay(100);
    yield put({ type: 'HIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section2' });

} else {
    yield put({ type: 'UNHIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section2' });
    delay(100);
    yield put({ type: 'HIDE_SECTION', sectionName: 'section1' });
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without adding a delay?

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch both sections in one function instead in two functions for each

---

```
yield put({ type: 'MODIFIED_SECTIONS', sections: [ { name: 'section1' , isHide: false }, { name: 'section2', isHide: true} ] }}
```

---

And while reduce use `isHide` flag to perform action on each section `name`